Use directive to change @Input attribute of component
I have the following components :
@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractControlComponent<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  ...
  @Input() warnings: string[] = [];
  ...
}

@Component({
  selector: 'test-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss']
})
export class InputComponent extends AbstractControlComponent<string> {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'test-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.scss']
})
export class DatepickerComponent extends AbstractControlComponent<Date> {
}


and a simple Directive where I would like to change the @Input property 'warnings' of my components.
@Directive({
    selector: '[validation]',
})
export class ValidationDirective {

 constructor(private readonly control: NgControl) {
    }

}

I tried to inject the AbstractComponent in the constructor :
  constructor(
        private readonly control: NgControl,
        @Host() readonly component: AbstractControlComponent<any>) {
    }

   ngOnInit(): void {
        this.component.warnings = ['test1', 'test2'];
    }


But it gives me an error :
Error: NG0201: No provider for _AbstractControlComponent found in NodeInjector
And I don't want to inject concrete components as my directive is generic.
Do you know how I can achieve that ?

As non standealone approach you declear everything right in your modules?

can you please provide a stackblitz link of your setup ?

The problem is that there really is no provider for AbstractControlComponent by the component itself. The component only inherits AbstractControlComponent but does not provide it.
In order to provide the concrete component as the AbstractControlComponent, you need to declare so in the providers:
@Component({
  selector: 'test-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
     { 
       provide: AbstractControlComponent,
       useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatepickerComponent)
     }
  ]
})
export class DatepickerComponent extends AbstractControlComponent<Date> {}

That way you'll be able inject the controller into the ValidationDirective.

From architectural point of view, I'd rather do things the other way around. Instead of writing into an input, I'd inject a class that provides the messasges into the AbstractControlComponent and read data from it.
export abstract class WarningSource {
   abstract get warnings(): string[]
}

@Directive()
export abstract class AbstractControlComponent<T> implements ControlValueAccessor {
  ...
  private warningSource = inject(WarningSource, { optional: true })
  get warnings() {
    return this.warningSource?.warnings ?? [];
  }
  ...
}


@Directive({
    selector: '[validation]',
    providers: [
     { 
       provide: WarningSource,
       useExisting: forwardRef(() => ValidationDirective)
     }
  ]
})
export class ValidationDirective extends WarningSource {
   warnings = ["This is a warning"]
}


I like your second option, but it gives me the following error : NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for WarningSource!.
First option works well ,  Thank You !

The second option needs to be optional when not all AbstractControls have the Validation directive. I've updated my code. Would appreciate feedback if it resolved the issue.

warningSource is not injected (null) in  AbstractControlComponent

You can use a custom injection token along with the @Host and @Optional decorators.
First you have to create the injection token:
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const ABSTRACT_CONTROL_COMPONENT = new InjectionToken<AbstractControlComponent<any>>('AbstractControlComponent');

Then provide it to your custom input components:
@Component({
  selector: 'test-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: ABSTRACT_CONTROL_COMPONENT, useExisting: InputComponent }
  ]
})
export class InputComponent extends AbstractControlComponent<string> { }

@Component({
  selector: 'test-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    { provide: ABSTRACT_CONTROL_COMPONENT, useExisting: DatepickerComponent }
  ]
})
export class DatepickerComponent extends AbstractControlComponent<Date> { }

After that you can inject the token in your directive:
import { Directive, Host, Optional, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ABSTRACT_CONTROL_COMPONENT } from './path-to-token-file';
import { AbstractControlComponent } from './path-to-abstract-component-file';

@Directive({
  selector: '[validation]',
})
export class ValidationDirective {
  constructor(
    private readonly control: NgControl,
    @Host() @Optional() @Inject(ABSTRACT_CONTROL_COMPONENT) readonly component: AbstractControlComponent<any>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.component) {
      this.component.warnings = ['test1', 'test2'];
    }
  }
}


You have to provide it, so that the component inside can find the  AbstractControlComponent. So that the component is available in injector. And the it should be available in the directive.
@Component({
  selector: 'test-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
      // provide the AbstractControlComponent
      {
            provide: AbstractControlComponent,
            useExisting: InputComponent 
        }
  ]

})
export class InputComponent extends AbstractControlComponent<string> {

